# WooCommerce Shopventory Integration with Filtering Attribute(s)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Sorry if the title is confusing - I'm working with a clothing store to bring their storefront online using WooCommerce. I'm familiar with how filtering works, however they use a third party integration software called Shopventory- I was able to load the products into the website just fine. However, they only use one attribute and its called 'Variant' when being uploaded to the site and thats where the sizes are. There are over 5000 products, and I wasn't sure if there was a way I can somehow create a variant with all this existing info?

It never actually created an official attribute or variations in WooCommerce. I know that I have to have that to use the filter by attribute widget, but is there anyway to somehow fix or make it acknowledge the fact that I do indeed have the same attribute (Variant) for every single product with different variants underneath that? I am so stumped and have absolutely no idea on how to figure this out.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Questions on how I can make myself more clear? I appreciate the help, I am absolutely stumped.